# Numba explanation/discussion. Why does my function not speed up at all?

Tags: python, numba, jit

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def func_jit(nums: np.ndarray, base: int, width: int = 4) -> np.ndarray:
    sol = np.empty(shape=(width, len(nums[0])), dtype=np.int64)
    fact = 1
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sol[i] = nums[i] * fact
        fact *= base
    return sol
```

Why does the @njit decorator not speed this function up at all? When running this function 20 times each with and without the decorator I get that they take roughly the same time on average - I am not counting the first jitted run that includes compiling.

Can someone explain why this is the case and maybe give some tips/hints for writing python code that will work well with jit or some other numba method?

I've tried running jit with a simpler function and got a significant runtime decrease, so numba.jit does work, and it does seem like the function I wrote is the problem.

Thank you!

P.s.: I'm trying to find a way to use numpy and numba to convert base 10 numbers to an arbitrarily large base. Maybe I should stick to converting one value at a time and instead use vectorize?

Comment: @TimRoberts Is `@njit(parallel=True)` solely supposed to parallelize? I thought Numba is primarily for compiling to lower level code (so it can run much faster even without parallelization).

Comment: @figure09 How are you calling/measuring it? And what are the runtimes?

Comment: @TimRoberts this is absolutely the sort of code that numba would improve drastically. Although, as you say, it won't be able to parallelize it for the reasons you stated, but it will be able to compile it down to efficient machine code

Comment: You really must provide a [mcve]. What arguments will this function get? How do you profile the run time?

Comment: You should at least provide an example. If I set `parallel=False` I easily get a 10x improvement depending on the size of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which might help would be to precompute the exponential function, then multiply it into into sol in a vectorized fashion.

```
def func_jit(nums: np.ndarray, base: int, width: int = 4) -> np.ndarray:
    sol = nums * (base ** np.arange(len(nums))).reshape(-1, 1)
    return sol
```

Of course, this also won't benefit from numba, because it spends most of its time inside NumPy.